# Delete the second digit of every two-digit numbers in Bigquery

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, digits

Given the following string

```
'FR8 - Y88, FRY - Y67, MX6 - EZY, A83 - A86'
```

what regular expression can I use to get the following string?

```
'FR8 - Y8, FRY - Y6, MX6 - EZY, A8 - A8'
```

Thou the aim is to identify all the second digit of two-digit numerbers and replace them with ''.

Thanks

I tried with \d(\d) but it continues to match both the numbers

Comment: actually I wrote it wrong: from the given string I would like to have 'FR - Y8, FRY - Y6, MX - EZY, A8 - A8'

Comment: regexp: (\S|^)(\d)(\D|$) , sub: $1$3 . It should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, r"(\D|^)(\d)\d(\D|$)", "$1$2$3")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o8fJRR/2).

*Details*:

- `(\D|^)` - Group 1: a non-digit or start of string (left-hand numeric boundary)
- `(\d)\d` - Group 2 capturing a digit and then another digit
- `(\D|$)` - Group 3: a non-digit char or end of string.

The replacement is a concatenation of the three groups.

Comment: Thanks but i get this result : FR8 - $1$2$3 FRY - $1$2$3 MX6 - EZY, $1$2$3- $1$2$3

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE(col, r"(\D|^)(\d)\d(\D|$)", "\\1\\2\\3") seems to work on BigQuery